# Feed multiple parquet files with wide data into TensorFlow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have list of `parquet` files in GCS containing wide data **(~10k columns + target column)**. I want to use Estimator API (i.e DNNClassifier) and feed this data into the classifier. My initial solution used `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` to which I've passed generator, which yielded my parquet files row-by-row. The problem is that because my data is wide, generating dictionaries row-by-row from the parquet files is really slow (~10 rows/s) and is degrading my training performance. Reading whole parquet file and transforming it to numpy array internally is super fast, but I cannot put this data into Estimator, because it complains that:

> features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s.

My generator:

```
def generator(files, columns):
    for file in files:
        df = pd.read_parquet(file)
        dict_df = df.loc[:, columns].to_dict("records")
        for record in zip(dict_df, df.loc[:, TARGET_COLUMN]):
            yield record, dict_df
```

Usage as `input_fn` for `Estimator`:

```
files = ["gs://asd", ...] # list of files
columns = ["f1", "f2", ...] # list of column names

def input_fn(files, columns, batch_size, num_epochs=100):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=lambda: generator(files, columns),
        output_types=({k: tf.float32 for k in columns}, tf.int32),
        output_shapes=({k: tf.TensorShape([]) for k in columns}, tf.TensorShape([]))
    ).repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)
```

I've experimented with `.prefetch()` but because this operation:

```
dict_df = df.loc[:, columns].to_dict("records")
```

takes most of the time, I'm stuck (I also tried to implement dict generation by hand, but it didn't help either).

**How to feed wide data from multiple files into TF Estimators efficiently?**